# regex search to the last slash in a path

Tags: regex, search, replace

All -

First let me say thank you to anyone who can (and does) offer to help solve this problem....Thank you!

I have style sheet paths that are several folders deep and I want to change any that I find to a single css folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/style/main.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/includes/style/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../includes/user/style/user.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/admin/css/style/admin.css" type="text/css" />
```

As you can see the path to user|admin|main.css is all over the place and I am trying to reference a central location.

I would like to find and replace the path info to read
**href="/css/[file name].css"**

This is what I have so far but I cannot figure out how to get it to go to the LAST slash before the file name

```
^<link rel="stylesheet" href=".*?(.*?[\/])
```

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of ways that you can target what you need and depending on how you want to perform your replacement (and what flavor of regular expressions you have at your disposal), they can vary.

I'll provide a few different uses that might help out.

**Matching the `href` Attribute**

If you wanted to replace the entire `href` section with a different value, you could use the following expression :

```
href=(["'].+\.css["'])
```

This will match everything within any `href` attributes as seen below using your example input :

[image]

**Matching `<link>` tags up to an `<href>`**

If you wanted to explicitly indicate that you only wanted to perform this for `<link>` tags, you could append the previous `<link ...` contents :

```
<link rel=['"]stylesheet['"] href=(['"].+\.css['"])
```

which would look like :

[image]

**Matching `<link>` tags until the CSS file**

Finally, if you only want to match the path up to, but not including the CSS file, you could use the following :

```
<link rel=['"]stylesheet['"] href=['"].+(?=\/.+\.css['"])
```

which would look like :

[image]

**Just grabbing the `href` until the CSS file**

```
href=['"].+(?=\/.+\.css['"])
```

[image]

Comment: your last two options worked for what I was looking for as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
href="[^"]+(\/[^.]+\.[^"]+)"
```

The `/filename.css` will be in `$1`.

It's not super optimized, because it needs to backtrack a little. (The `href="[^"]+` will initially gobble up the entire path.)

Alternatively, you could use this regex:

```
href="[^"]+(\/[^"\/]+)"
```

They both give the same results on the test data.

---

To help you a bit more, the replacement should be something like `href="YOUR_PATH$1"`. Your path may need to be escaped first.

Comment: Laurel - Thank you.  Your solution was close and maybe I missed something by not understanding what you meant by $1.  I was able to take what you posted and with a few changes, I did get what I was looking for.
What I ended up with was - href="[^"]+(\/[^.]+\/)

Comment: @user6352295 `$1` refers to the contents of the first capture group. Sometimes it's known as `\1`

Comment: Thank you for the info - as you might have guessed, I am learning this on the fly.  Funny thing is, now I have the search part working and thought it would be a simple to replace it with what I need it to be but turns out nothing is that simple.  Now, I have to figure out how to construct the replace string.

Comment: @user6352295 I've edited my answer to indicate how you might go about replacing things. I hope it helps.